# what is causing random spikes in local mysql server query speeds?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So while playing around on my localhost in phpMyAdmin and doing some stuff with SQL, I realized that I would randomly get huge spikes in the time it took to perform a database query. I have a database table with about 3000 entries, and I was running a very simple query to display the first 2500 of them.

On average, running this query was taking around 0.003 to 0.004 seconds. (Of course, loading the phpMyAdmin page took much longer, but we're just looking at the query times.) However, I noticed that occasionally the query times would go up past 0.01. Once it even shot up to 0.04. So, my curiosity getting the better of me, I decided to repeatedly run the same query, and produced a graph of my results:

[image]

I'm not running anything else on my computer that may be interacting with MySQL, and because it's my localhost I'm the only one that's doing anything to mess with my database (right?). Slight outliers are understandable, but what's causing the load times to go up anywhere from 3 to 30 times, completely randomly it seems?

Can anyone help me satiate my curiosity?

Comment: Disk cache misses are expensive. Random disk I/O is unavoidable, and causes some cache misses on unrelated places.

Comment: Probably something to do with memory or processor load.

Comment: You can't really guarantee deterministic results on a modern PC, unless you were to run a real-time OS, even if you *think* nothing else is going on in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not running anything else on my computer that may be interacting with MySQL

But is there anything else running on your computer that might be interacting with your hard drive /CPU on a regular basis? Because that would explain the spikes. Maybe have a scan of running processes, and compare the cpu/disk activity against the spikes.

Comment: Do you know of any tool that can log the I/O activity for all processes?

Comment: What OS are you running? On Windows you can use Resource Monitor, I'm afraid I don't know if it's Mac or Linux but I am sure someone here will!

Comment: Do you mean `resmon.exe`? As far as I know, it only sees one minute into the past, and it cannot export the data. Do you know of any software that can provide a long-term dump of said data in some readable format (XLS will do)? I'm using Windows 7, but I don't know what the asker uses.

Comment: You can use Performance Monitir, it can log and export the data. [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx]

Answer (score 0):

Even though your database is running on your local host, it's not running in complete isolation.  It is competing for your system's resources with every other process you have running.